# Override Tpanel.MouseDown To Change Color

Tags: delphi, panel

How do I override TPanel's mouse down so that every time I click the panel it will change color? I tried this code but wont work:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, 
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TPanelAA = class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TPanelAA.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Color := $0000FF;
end;

procedure TPanelAA.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('mouse down');
  inherited;
  Color := $0000FF;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('standard', [TPanelAA]);
end;

end.
```

I'm not good in "inheriting/overriding" things. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, there's a paint method? @TLama, would you take this one?

Comment: @Sertac, no. You were faster :)

Comment: @Ago, to format a code in the question, select the code text and click the `{}` button in the editor window, or press `CTRL + K`. And, don't attempt to use `<blink>` tag. It is ignored here and we don't need to have your code blink to us :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert

```
ParentBackground := False;
```

before you set the color. This is done automatically at design time when you change the color from the default, but at run time you need it.

**Edit**: Don't set the color again in the overriden Paint handler, you don't need it (although it won't have an effect since the color is not changing). (Credit @TLama - I didn't even notice the override in the original unformatted code).